# Filter a string to contain only alnum chars + a hyphen?

Tags: php, regex

I would like to filter a string and strip all characters that are not alphanumeric or a hyphen. Is there some tunction in PHP for that?

Not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use a regular expression to search for such strings and then replace them with the empty string. The expression could look like: `[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]`

See [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)